# VM production server and low entropy

Tags: linux, virtualization, entropy

I'm monitoring a VM functioning as our production server.
I noticed it has at many times, quite low entropy (/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail).

On average our server(which among other stuff does SSL, session-key generation etc) runs with about 100-200 bits of available entropy.

Is this anything to be concerned with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds normal for a vm.  You don't typically worry unless available entropy drops below that 100-200 average.  The key measure is the sequences that come out of that entropy.

You should use [the `ent` program](http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/) to test your random sequences.  You worry when you start seeing tests fail here.

[This](https://calomel.org/entropy_random_number_generators.html) site has a good process for testing randomness.

> We can collect random data from /dev/random using "dd". This command will collect 8,192 blocks from /dev/random and output the results to the text file we will call "random_output". NOTE: if your /dev/random generator is too slow this command will take forever to finish. The random_output file should be around 1 to 4 megabytes in size depending on how large a chuck is on your system. For now, if the dd command does not finish in 3 seconds or so hit Ctrl-c to kill dd.

`dd if=/dev/random of=random_output count=8192`

Then, after you've built your ent program:

`./ent random_output`

Analyzing the results is a little beyond the scope of your question, but what I linked can fill in the ancillary details.

Comment: Awesome suggestion :) thanks.
Just adding that if you're running a debian-based system, chances are that the ent program is very likely available through the package manager